# Difference between JavaScript Closure and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a little bit of experience in JavaScript but JavaScript Closure makes me confused.

Comment: Java Closure or JavaScript closures?

Comment: Javascript Closures and Javascript

Comment: do you mean closures, as in the language construct, or Closure, as in the google code project for compiling JavaScript? http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/

Comment: @jvenema thanks, I have never seen this link

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Zero votes. Zero answers accepted. If you don't get help this might be the reason, so consider improving it.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what the closure is going to do, you need to understand the scope of local variables.

In Java, you can declare a new, distinct local variable in any {} block.

In Javascript, there is different behavior. The interpreter allows declaring a local variable anywhere, but these variables will only be distinct if they are in different functions.

There is no loop scope or loop-defined variables in Javascript, so `for(x=0;x<10;x++){ var j=...`  behaves exactly like  `var j; for(x=0; x<10; x++){ j = ..`

This is why in Javascript one often wraps one function in another function in order to create a well behaved scope.

Comment: you means like write the function in jquery or Is it smiliar jquery, javascript closure and Ajax?

Comment: Thanks Paul. where can I use javascript Closure? Is it useful or not

Comment: jQuery is a library of prewritten JavaScript. A closure is a language construct. Ajax is the technique of using JS to communicate with a webserver. You are comparing a motor parts shop to an engine and to driving to the beach.